# Ubuntu – disable password prompt on local login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have an Ubuntu computer set up in my flat running a couple of websites and webservices. I usually log into it via ssh, but sometimes I want to access it physically, and that is where the problem lies: I cannot log in to the server as I don't want to enter my 128-char password on a keyboard.

There are three use-cases when I log into that server:

1. From a trusted place. I have some ssh keys there, so I log in via ssh from my work machine or laptop without having to enter my 128-char password.
2. From a relatively untrusted place. Sometimes I have to log into the server from a non-standard place, for example, from a friend's PC or customer's laptop, so I cannot easily disable password-based ssh login. And I have no problems with entering the password, as I have it in a KeyPass storage. Ctrl+C Ctrl+V saves my life.
3. From another trusted place (the flat). When I physically come near the server, I don't want to enter that password – I want to be already authenticated by having a physical access to the server. The problem is that I don't know how to tell the local terminal it must not ask the password, just let me in without any security measures: I mean, having a key from a front door is a security measure.

I tried Googling it, but I couldn't find a correct wording for the search query, and all the stuff I found is to run `passwd -d`. Some other articles say writing `PasswordAuthentication no` to `/etc/sshd_config`. But, as you could guess, both ways contradict my second usecase. :/

Long story short, is there any way to permit a passwordless login from a local terminals, while leaving logins from remote terminals password-protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another user with a simpler password and configure `sshd` to NOT allow that user to be used (see `AllowUsers` on the `sshd_config` file). This way, you can only use the username when you're on a local terminal. Also, grant it `sudo` permissions and then simply run:

```
sudo su
su - your_original_user
```

Comment: I've thought about doing so, but it is not as "beautiful" as I want for it to be. It requires manual input on every login, but there has to be a way to make it automatic. Perhaps, run these commands automatically on logging in on certain `tty`s? I don't know how to discriminate local terminals from remote ones, though. %)

Comment: Maybe not beautiful, but functional. Logins exist for a reason, even if you have access to a local console, there's still a risk, there should be some kind of security and it is achieved with a password.

Comment: Alright, you've persuaded me. I'll have a separate user for local logins with a weaker, but human-typeable password. By the way, what do you think of putting `sudo su - main_user_name` into `~/.profile` of a new user, as it described in https://askubuntu.com/a/270050? Will it work?

Comment: Sure it will, I have had similar configurations. But make sure to modify your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration and list under `AllowUsers` only those logins that you want to allow SSH to (i.e., not listing this new login).

Comment: Alright, thank you! I will try that in several hours, I hope I won't make any catastrophic mistakes. :D

Comment: Your answer saves my life for the second time.